# How do I quit a while(scanf_s...) loop?

Tags: c++, scanf

My Visual Studio tells me to use `scanf_s()`, and now that I've used it, my `while` loop goes on forever. Let's say I'm reading lines, where each line has two numbers separated with a space. Once I've inserted all the numbers, my `while` never stops.  How do I quit my loop?

```cpp
int main() {
    
    int i,j;
    while (scanf_s("%d %d", &i, &j)) {
        int maxLength = 0;
        for (int index = i; index <= j; index++) {
            int tmp = cycle(index);
            if (tmp > maxLength) {
                maxLength = tmp;
            }
        }
        printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, maxLength);
    }
    
    cout << "lol";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The elephant in the room: Are you sure you want to use `scanf` and friends at all in a C++ program? `while (std::cin >> i >> j)` does exactly what you want and you don't have to worry about messing up the format arguments or misinterpreting the return code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My Visual Studio tells me to use scanf_s,

Dubious advice, but standard in MS-land (as an alternative to `scanf`).

> and now that i've used it my
> while goes on forever.

That's not a distinction between `scanf_s` and `scanf`.  Both return the number of fields successfully converted and assigned.  Both will keep waiting indefinitely for input until they see non-matching data or the end of the file.  Both return `EOF`, **which is nonzero**, when the end of the file is reached without scanning any fields.

> Let's say i'm reading lines, where each line
> has to numbers seperated with a space. Once ive inserted all the
> numbers my while never stops. How do i quit my loop?

Test for the specific expected return value, not its general truthiness:

```
    while (scanf_s("%d %d", &i, &j) == 2) { // ...
```

If you're reading from a regular file then that's sufficient by itself, but if you're reading an indefinite amount of interactive input then you must rely on the user to provide some kind of indicator that they have no more to provide.  They can send an end-of-file signal (<ctrl-Z> on Windows), or in this case, they could also enter a line containing a character that is neither whitespace nor a decimal digit nor a '+' or '-' (which will remain unread in the input).

Answer (score 3):

`scanf_s` returns the number of fields translated on success.  On error it returns either `0` or `EOF`.

Your logic is assuming that any non-zero value is success.  When the return value is EOF, that assumption breaks.

Try comparing against the number of fields you need:

```
while (2 == scanf_s("%d %d", &i, &))
```